# Is there a best practice for inserting an HTML chunk with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I've got a large-ish chunk of HTML in my document:

```
<div class="largecontainer">
    <div class="largeeditor"><textarea class="largetextarea"></textarea><div class="largepreview"></div></div>
<div class="largecontrols editcontrols">
    <input type="button" name="save" value="Save" class="saveeventbutton taskbuttons">
    <input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" class="deletetaskbutton taskbuttons">
    <input type="button" name="contract" value="Contract" class="contractbutton taskbuttons">
    <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="cancelbutton taskbuttons">
</div>
<div class="largecontrols viewcontrols">
    <input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" class="editbutton taskbuttons">
    <input type="button" name="contract" value="Contract" class="contractbutton taskbuttons">
</div>
<div class="fade"></div>
```

This HTML does nothing. It's not content. It's not a template. It's presentation-related, but by default, the CSS is set to `display: none`, which changes after a user presses a button and some Javascript goes off.

I could include it with a `<link>`, stick it between some `<template>` tags, or load it with my Javascript.

Loading it with Javascript seems the most appealing to me, because it won't clutter the document with what's obviously not content-related, and it's not downloaded until it needs to be.

Comment: I've seen `<script type="text/html">` used by some frameworks to indicate a template. That said, I'm not sure there's a best practice, per se - the three methods you outlines clearly have subtly different advantages or disadvantages, so use the one best appropriate for your situation? (I'm not sure you're saving a lot of performance by having a HTTP request load this on demand though, unless you're trying to optimizing first-load time specifically.)

Comment: Do you know if a `<script type="text/html" src="largeeditor">` type solution would work, or would that be finicky because there's no text in the tag?

Comment: An iframe element (from the same domain as the parent page) to implement the edit widget in HTML, dynamically created when needed...

Comment: Another option:  JSX, if you are using a transpiler.  https://facebook.github.io/jsx/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application architecture, handling html with JavaScript may be acceptable and appropriate.

However, after working on an application that relies heavily on this practice I have found:

1. It is generally harder to read, edit, modify html in JavaScript code. Did you properly close all elements and quoted attributes?
2. Finding html snippets is harder if you don't have a good system in place. It's harder for new developers who aren't familiar with the application. It's much easier to search html in *.html files.
3. Code editors will give you better html hints if you've made syntax errors in an html page rather than a script page.

If you are just hiding showing content I would much rather write out both blocks and use JavaScript to modify the css style to make these elements visible.

Comment: I don't plan on manipulating the HTML in any way, just inserting it, and I do want to keep it in HTML files. The solution I have right now _works_, I just hide and show the elements as appropriate, but it's odd to have a bunch of HTML in my document that's invisible and doesn't do anything until some JS acts on it.

Comment: Then I may have misunderstood you earlier. Your usage sounds like typical AJAX techniques.

Comment: so making an AJAX request for the HTML and pasting it in would be considered a best practice in this case?

Comment: If hiding and displaying conditionally works for your case, that is what I'd do. I'd mess with a handrolled template system if a single "type" of block was used an arbitrary amount of times in a document. I believe "typical AJAX" techniques was supposed to mean just that - the AJAX request returns some data that you use to decide what elements to hide/show, and what values to populate them with.